# Incorrect number of threads shown from node.js os.cpus() when clustering in AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, multithreading, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing, cluster-computing

Is there a way to get access to all 324 threads in the AWS `c4.8xlarge` instance from node.js? Is there another way to get the number of threads besides `os.cpus()` ?

We are using a CPU-optimized AWS instance of size `c4.8xlarge` which has 36 virtual CPUs each with 9 cores, which is a total of 324 threads (36 x 9).

When we run this script to measure the number of threads, it shows 36, but it does not show any information about the 9 cores on each vCPU.

```
 const cluster = require('cluster');
 const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

 if (cluster.isMaster) {
   console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

   // Fork workers.
   for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
     cluster.fork();
   }

   cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
     console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
   });
 } else {
     console.log("Number of cores: " + numCPUs);
     process.exit(0);
 }
```

This is a problem because we run this script on another machine that has 1 CPU and 8 hyper-threaded cores and it reports 16 CPUs (which is correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to various sources (including [a blog article on Amazon's site](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-new-c4-instances/)), a 'c4.8xlarge' has 18 hyperthreaded cores, *totalling* 36 vCPUs (which [are hyperthreaded cores](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=613108)).

Comment: This is correct, although I believe there's an extra word at the end, and this should say *"36 vCPUs (which are hyperthreads)."*

Comment: Thanks for dredging up that article. That is the key info there: "In some cases, your workload might not need all 18 of the cores (each of which runs two hyperthreads, for a total of 36 vCPUs on c4.8xlarge)."